# Converting multiple select to appear as a regular select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input, uniform

I'm currently slicing up a new site design and I want to make a multiple select look and feel the same way that a regular select does, but have the user control+click to choose multiple options.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this goal? I am using the uniform js plugin with jQuery for the rest of my input styles.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="1">
...
</select>
```

This won't behave as a non-multiple select element.

---

Since you are using jQuery already, I would suggest [**jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget**](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).